# Any TTS api for Android in turkish?

Tags: android, api, turkish, text-to-speech

Is there any free TTS (text-to-speech) service for Android in Turkish?  I've not found anything useful in google.

Comment: If device's language is setted to Turkish, TTS start to speak in Turkish :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didnt try it yet on android, but I recently discovered this one: http://www.ispeech.org
The speech quality looks promising on the web app.

Give it a shot :)

Comment: thanks,i've seen and i'll try it as soon as possible , i'm writing virtual tour guide program so i actually need one but free ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use Google TTS as below:

```
strText =  converToTurkishCharacter(strText);
     if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {


                            @Override
                            public void onInit(int status) {

                                Locale locale = new Locale("tr_TR");//set Locale
                                textToSpeech.setLanguage(locale);


                                if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {

                                }
                                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {


                                    String[] text = strText.split("\\.");//split with every "dot"

                                    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
                                        HashMap uttrerance = new HashMap();
                                        uttrerance.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, Integer.toString(i));
                                        textToSpeech.speak(text[i], 1, uttrerance);

                                    }
                                }


                                //-------checks engine
                                List engineList = textToSpeech.getEngines();

                                for(Object strEngine : engineList){
                                    Log.d("tagg",strEngine.toString());
                                    if(strEngine.toString().equals("EngineInfo{name=com.google.android.tts}")){//check if google tts api engine is installed on device

                                        isGoogleAvaible = true;
                                    }
                                }
                                if(!isGoogleAvaible){
                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ActivityColumnistArticle.this,
                                            "Google TTS Eksik...Lutfen yukleyin", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                                    toast.show();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.tts"));
                                    startActivity(intent);//user should install google tts , if it is defaultly not installed
                                }
                                //---------------For missing data
                                int code = textToSpeech.isLanguageAvailable(locale);
                                if (code == -2 || code == -1) {
                                    Intent installIntent = new Intent();
                                    installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                                    startActivity(installIntent);
                                }
                            }

                        }, "com.google.android.tts");
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ActivityColumnistArticle.this,
                                "Ses destegi icin minumum Icecream Sandwich yuklu olmalı...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                        toast.show();
                    }
```

Moreover, Google TTS have bug with türkish character like "ö", "ğ" so that you should convert them with unicode:

```
    private String converToTurkishCharacter(String text){


           text = text.replace("\u015f", "\u015f");
           text = text.replace("\u00e7", "\u00e7");
           text = text.replace("\u011f", "\u011f");
           text = text.replace("\u0131", "\u0131");
           text = text.replace("\u00fc", "\u00fc");
           text = text.replace("\u00f6", "\u00f6");
          // ----
           text = text.replace("\u011e", "\u011e");
           text = text.replace("\u0130", "\u0130");
           text = text.replace("\u00d6", "\u00d6");
           text = text.replace("\u00dc", "\u00dc");
           text = text.replace("\u015e", "\u015e");
           text = text.replace("\u00c7", "\u00c7");
           return  text;
       }
```

Some android device have pico TTS only, so that is why you check Google TTS, and ask user to install...

*Not:In order tts to work,You should have real android device*

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem in my case,

define that variable:

> final Locale locale = new Locale("tr", "TR");

in onCreate method:

> ```
>       tts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new
>       TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onInit(int status) {
>
>                  if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
>                     int result = tts.setLanguage(locale);
>                     if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
>                             || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
>                         tts.speak("bir sorun oluştu", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
>                     }
>                 } else {
>                     tts.speak("bir sorun oluştu.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
>                     Log.d(TAG, "Text to speech is not successful");
>                 }
>             }
>         });
>        tts.speak("bağlanıyor", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
> ```

it will say "bağlanıyor"

Answer (score 0):

just use **Locale.getDefault()**

`tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault())`