# How to set turkish language text to speech

Tags: android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I need to use TTS and STT. I did STT part but i didn't find turkish language supported for TTS.
I don't know how to add turkish language TTS.

Comment: look my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311274/any-tts-api-for-android-in-turkish/36784975#36784975

Answer (score 1):

Check from `TTS` what languages are available first. For *Turkish* i think you can do something like:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("tr", "TR");
result = tts.setLanguage(locale);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set Locale language turkish

```
TextToSpeech.setLanguage(new Locale("tr-TR"));
```

Pass string in turkish language for `TTS`