# Android Text to Speech in Turkish

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have problem with pronouncing Turkish characters using Google tts api. It doesn't say anything when i use Utf8 chars for example "ş","ı","ö". How can i solve it?

```html
    public void onInit(int status) {
 
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
 
         Locale locale = new Locale("tr", "TR");
        int result = tts.setLanguage(locale);
   
           
 
            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else {
             bCevir.setEnabled(true);
                speakOut();
            }
 
        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }
 
    }
    
    
    private void speakOut() {
     String Str = null;
  Str="Nasılsın";
     
        tts.speak(Str, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
      
}
```

Comment: look my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311274/any-tts-api-for-android-in-turkish/36784975#36784975

Answer (score 3):

The problem was solved. It has nothing to do with us or code. It's because of Google text to speech engine that it is ok after last TTS update.