# How to make TextToSpeech language turkish voice

Tags: android, android-studio, text-to-speech, speech-to-text, voice-recognition

I'm using Android Studio. Code java.I want to make TextToSpeech language Turkish.How can I make the voice Turkish?

my code:

```
TextToSpeech textToSpeech ;
ImageView ımagespeech;

textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int i) {
                if (i !=TextToSpeech.ERROR){
                    textToSpeech.setLanguage(new Locale("en_US"));
                    textToSpeech.setSpeechRate((float)1.0);
                }
            }
        });

        ımagespeech.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String gettext =tvtcontextt.getText().toString();
                textToSpeech.speak(gettext,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
            }
        });


@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (textToSpeech != null ){
            textToSpeech.stop();
            textToSpeech.shutdown();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried "tr_TR" instead of "en_US"?

Comment: Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36784975/10695663) out

Comment: @MehranB yes i tried but it doesn't speak. Does not say anything. The link did not happen either

Answer (score 0):

I recently discovered this [languages](http://www.ispeech.org). The speech quality looks promising on the web app.

Give it a shot :)

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution,
in this way the code selects the language used in the device:

```
private TextToSpeech tts;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
    tts = new TextToSpeech(requireContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                //int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US"));
                int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.forLanguageTag(Locale.getDefault().toLanguageTag()));
                if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                    Log.e("TTS", "The Language not supported!");
                } else {
                    Log.d("TTS", "TTS its working");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}


// in your code
tts.speak("read this", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "");


@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```